# A question about vector bundle isomorphisms

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles

Let $E\to X\times[0, 1]$ be a vector bundle. Define a map $i_t:X\to X\times[0, 1]$ by $i_t(x)=(x, t)$. Then we know the vector bundles $i_0^*E$ and $i_1^*E$ are isomorphic, and probably there are many such bundle isomorphisms. Is there any chance that these bundle isomorphisms are homotopic?

Comment: The space of bundle isomorphisms is a torsor over $[X, GL_n]$ and $\pi_0$ of this space is the set of homotopy classes of maps $X \to GL_n$, and there's no reason this should be a point (e.g. when $n = 1$ it can be identified with $H^1(X, \mathbb{Z})$).